# Hiding Filters In Certain Categories in magento

Tags: filter, attributes, magento-1.7, layer

on our high level category there are about 50 filter options, i m trying to hide attribute filter with xml code in custom layout of categories. with this code

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
<action method="setData">
    <instruction>hide_attribute_code</instruction>
    <value>1</value>
</action>
```

but not success
we have get many suggestion but we have not perfect solution of this problem
check it on this url - http://www.bindaaslo.com/mobile-tablets.html/

Answer (score 0):

to disable the layered navigation(Shopping Options), go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and select the attributes that appear in your layered navigation, and select “NO” from “Use In Layered Navigation” drop down.. the layered navigation automatically disappears when u do this to all the attributes that appear in layered navigation..

Comment: im also know that  my question is to disable disable appearing in layer navigation, we have hide only in selected category